# RESTful service

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have to write a RESTful service with client but have some problems with functions because cant figure what Media Type they should @Produces.

Basically I have a few operations with strings: counting words, finding the index of a substring, counting symbols and reversing a string.

I have no problems with reversing the string, but with other three I am facing a problem because it seems that I can`t @Produce an int for some reason.

What type should I use so that I can @Produce an int so I can return it?

Here is my Java code:

```
 public int getNumberOfWords(java.lang.String parameter) {

 int words;

        String [] sentence = parameter.split(" ");
        words = sentence.length;

        return words;





 public int getNumberOfSymbols(java.lang.String parameter) {
        //TODO implement this method
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet.");
   return (int) parameter.chars()
            .distinct()
            .count();



 public java.lang.String invertString(java.lang.String text) {
    //TODO implement this method
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet.");
     int i, len = text.length();
StringBuilder dest = new StringBuilder(len);

for (i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--){
    dest.append(text.charAt(i));
}

return dest.toString();



 public int findSubstr(java.lang.String text, java.lang.String substr) {
      return text.indexOf(substr);
```

So the first 3 functions are problematic.  I even tried with @Produces application/json type.

Answer (score 0):

@Produces("application/json") this will allow you to return json from your method basically most of the RESTFull has to mapped to an object in the client side, even if it is simple thing like a String, or Integer.

Comment: When i am using it i even can`t deploy my service

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible return an int, @Produces defines which MIME type is provided by the method. In your case the most suitable should be plain text.

Comment: So basically i must find way to cast that int to string and then return it ? @Miguelángel Cárdenas G